# To JOIN 2 tables using Onclick function in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, drop-down-menu, onclick, join

I have a 2 drop down list, which contains table names of Postgres database. Now I have JOIN tables after selected by the user.
Here I have a code implemented for drop down list.

**test.php**

```
$resultLevel = pg_query($conn, "SELECT f_table_name FROM geometry_columns"); 
if (!$resultLevel) {
echo "An error occured.\n";
exit;
}
echo "LEVEL: \t";
echo "<select name='cat'><option value=''>Select one</option>";
while($noticia = pg_fetch_array($resultLevel)) {
echo  "<option value='$noticia[f_table_name]'>$noticia[f_table_name]</option>";
}
echo "</select>\n";
$resultParameter = pg_query($conn, "SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE column_name != 'the_geom' AND column_name= 'districtcode'");
if (!$resultParameter) {
echo "An error occured.\n";
exit;
}
echo "\n PARAMETER:";                               
echo "<select name='subcat'><option value=''>Select one</option>";
while($noticia1 = pg_fetch_array($resultParameter)) {
echo  "<option value='$noticia1[table_name]'>$noticia1[table_name]</option>";
}
echo "</select>";`
```

Now I have JOIN table from level and table from parameter.
The tables in drop down list are

```
LEVEL:(Drop down list 1)

DISTRICT:
distco(pkey), district, shp_area, shp_length, popln.

TALUK:
talukco(pkey),taluk, distco, district, shp_area, shp_length, popln.

GP:
gpco(pkey),gp,talukco,taluk, distco, district, shp_area, shp_length, popln.

PARAMETER:(Drop down list 2)

SCHOOL:
id(pkey),gpco,gp,talukco,taluk, distco, district, govt_school, pvt_school.

LITERACY:
id(pkey),gpco,gp,talukco,taluk, distco, district, m_lit, f_lit.

HOSPITALS:
id(pkey),gpco,gp,talukco,taluk, distco, district, govt_hosp, pvt_hosp
```

How to JOIN the above mentioned tables at runtime and I have to display it in tabular form.
I am not getting how to impart a JOIN query on onclick function in real time.
Can any one help form this.
thanks in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
<?php
//NB added form tag here
echo "<form>";
echo "LEVEL: \t";
//NB added js onchange 
echo "<select name='cat' onchange="javascript: this.form.submit()"><option value=''>Select one</option>"; ///NB asd
while($noticia = pg_fetch_array($resultLevel)) {
echo  "<option value='$noticia[f_table_name]'>$noticia[f_table_name]</option>";
}
..................
//NB modified query here
$resultParameter = pg_query($conn, "SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE column_name != 'the_geom' AND column_name= ".$_POST['cat']);
```